# Android ViewPager and Fragment serialization

Tags: android, serialization, android-fragments, android-viewpager, parcelable

I've an activity with two attributes:

- private Fragment firstFragment;
- private Fragment secondFragment;

In onCreate method:

```
    adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(6);
    pager.setSaveEnabled(true);
```

where MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter class.
Into getItem() method:

```
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        switch (position) {
            case FIRST:
                secondFragment = new FirstFragment();
                secondFragment.setArguments(args);
                return secondFragment;
            case SECOND:
                secondFragment = new SecondFragment();
                secondFragment.setArguments(args);
                return secondFragment;
        }
    }
```

and all works correctly.

But, when I change the screen orientation, the private attributes is set to null and I lost the reference of two fragments.
So i've tried to serialized this fragment with:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, FirstFragment.class.getName(), firstFragment);
    getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState, SecondFragment.class.getName(), secondFragment);
}
```

and load them into onCreate method with:

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        firstFragment = (FirstFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, FirstFragment.class.getName());
        secondFragment = (SecondFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, SecondFragment.class.getName());
    }
```

My questions:

**1. Is it the correct way to serialized fragment into activity screen orientation changes?**

**2. Sometimes I've the error: "Unmarshalling unknown type code 55 at offset 448", is it possible that it has caused by fragment serialization?"**

EDIT:

I need to have the fragments as activity attributes because I've a listener interface into activity that:

```
@Override
public void executeTask(String what) {
    secondFragment.executeTask(what);
}
```

this method was invoked into firstFragment. So the FirstFragment can execute a method of SecondFragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what may be the cause of the problem but I'll give you a hint that may help.

I don't think that you should reference the `Fragments` in the `Adapter` from the `Activity`.
Mainly due to the fact that it's pretty hard to synchronize the `Activity` life-cycle, `Fragment` lifecycle and `ViewPager` children life-cycles. And if any bugs emerge the debugging can be really painful.
Believe me, been there, done that...

By the way - is there a reason why you need references to `Fragments` in your `Activity` ?

EDIT

I don't think you should pass the information between the `Fragments` this way. In general the `FragmentManager` handles (creates, deletes) `Fragments` on it's own and you cannot be sure that these `Fragments` will be available at any time.

I think that the best way would be to move your data to separate model (database entry, `SharedPreference` or a singelton class) and then letting know the `Adapter` that data has changed (by a `DataObserver` in `Fragments` or simply notify the `Adapter` to update children data by calling `notifyDataChanged`).

EXAMPLE

FragmentA --->listener (`reloadData()`)--->Activity--->`adapter.notifyDataChanged()`-----> fragmentB gets updated

This way if you ever want to add a `ThirdFragment` or in fact any number of `Fragments` that will use the Data you will not have to worry about updating data in any of these - just let the `Adapter` worry about it.

Comment: This is a good workaround and, probably, this is the right way to solve the fragment serialization. Using DataObserver for change loaded data into a fragment and a business module to perform any other type of operations.

Answer (score 0):

If your using same layout for portrait and landscape then When orientation change you can avoid activity recreate. change your manifest as...

```
     <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
     </activity>
```

and then override onConfigurationChanged() in activity ...

```
    @Override
     public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration        newConfig)
    {
      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with same layout? The structure of components? I've some layouts file into layout-normal-land, etc...

Comment: Are you using same layout for Portrait and landscape? then you can avoid saving the state when orientation change.

Comment: No, I'm using a different xml for this view.